# Bubble Sort Highest to Lowest (Python)

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort

Hi could someone help me so instead of sorting from lowest to highest, sort it form highest to lowest.

```
def sort_list(to_short):
    for i in range(len(to_short)):
        for j in range(len(to_short) - 1):
            if to_short[j] < to_short[j + 1]:
                to_short[j], to_short[j + 1] = to_short[j + 1], to_short[j]
```

Comment: What happens if you change the "less than" symbol to a "greater than" symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the symbol in the if condition, here is a code with the two ways (lowest to highest and highest to lowest) in your function:

```
def inplace_bubble_sort(to_sort, lower_first=True):
    for i in range(len(to_sort)):
        for j in range(len(to_sort) - 1):
            if lower_first:
                sort_condition = to_sort[j] > to_sort[j + 1]
            else:
                sort_condition = to_sort[j] < to_sort[j + 1]
            if sort_condition:
                to_sort[j], to_sort[j + 1] = to_sort[j + 1], to_sort[j]


a = [3, 4, 2, 31, 6, 1]
inplace_bubble_sort(a)
print(a)
inplace_bubble_sort(a, lower_first=False)
print(a)

result: 
first print -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 31] 
second print -> [31, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```