# bubble sort: how to move smaller element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, bubble-sort

```py
from random import randint

lst = [randint(0,100) for i in range(5)]
print(lst)
for i in range(len(lst)-1):
    for j in range(len(lst)-i-1):
        if lst[j] > lst[j+1]:
            lst[j], lst[j+1] = lst[j+1], lst[j]
print(lst)
```

How do I change the code so that the smaller element moves. In this code I move the biggest element to the right and I need the small one to the left.

I tried to do cherks step -1 but I don't understand how

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bubble Sort Highest to Lowest (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67205793/bubble-sort-highest-to-lowest-python)

Answer (score 0):

Work backwards in your second loop by changing it to : `for j in range(len(lst)-2,i-1,-1)` or `reversed(range(i,len(lst)-1))`

Comment: Why -2 in range?

Comment: Because you will want `j` to start at the position before last so that the comparisons of  `lst[j] > lst[j+1]` doesn't go beyond the end of the list (at j+1).   Since the last position in `lst` is at `len(lst)-1` , the position before last is at `len(lst)-2`